# handling expression language exceptions in UpdateAttribute

Tags: apache-nifi

Is there anyway to control the behaviour of UpdateAttribute when an exception occurs in an expression for an attribute it is adding?

I am seeing a continuous stream of ProcessException exceptions generated by an UpdateAttribute processor from an expression when a flow file arrives with invalid data. From what I see in the documentation ProcessException is considered to be retriable but in this case the data is not going to change, and there is no way to limit the number of tries.

The ProcessException reported is

```
2021-02-09 11:34:47,421 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-5] o.a.n.p.attributes.UpdateAttribute UpdateAttribute[id=e3d11ce6-327b-1b5b-e764-xxx] Failed to process session due to org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: Unable to evaluate new value for attribute 'processing_end_time': org.apache.nifi.attribute.expression.language.exception.IllegalAttributeException: Cannot parse attribute value as a date; date format: yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss; attribute value: N.: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: Unable to evaluate new value for attribute 'processing_end_time':
```

The underlying exception is

```
Caused by: org.apache.nifi.attribute.expression.language.exception.IllegalAttributeException: Cannot parse attribute value as a date; date format: yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss; attribute value: N
        at org.apache.nifi.attribute.expression.language.evaluation.functions.StringToDateEvaluator.evaluate(StringToDateEvaluator.java:65)
        at org.apache.nifi.attribute.expression.language.evaluation.cast.WholeNumberCastEvaluator.evaluate(WholeNumberCastEvaluator.java:45)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an [open case](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-5448) to add a failure path for Update Attribute. As a workaround, you could use a scripting processor such as ExecuteScript to do the attribute update, as you could catch the exception yourself and route the flow file to failure. Another option might be to do some "side-channel" checks, such as checking if the attribute value has a length of 19. If not, it's not going to be in the desired format so you can route those to failure before trying to treat the others as a date.

Comment: Thanks for your insight

Comment: Thinking about this some more while reviewing the one NiFi job that I have written, I believe the answer is to validate the flow file before it flows to UpdateAttribute.  In my case I use ValidateCSV so that any invalid lines go to a failure queue. 

For all the errors I see, which are someone else's dataflow, the flow file contains text from a file, so I expect that running the text through ValidateRecord might work.